# Permission Audit log categories

Tags: 2013, permissions, audit-log-reports

When we pull SharePoint audit log reports for "Editing users and permissions", we see the following categories:

- Security Group Create
- Security Group Member Add
- Security Group Member Delete
- Security Role Bind Break Inherit
- Security Role Bind Inherit
- Security Role Bind Update

What do these mean?
In particular, what does "Security Role Bind Update" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Go to Central Administration and manage Service Applications
2. Select Secure Store Service
3. Then Click on the Properties in the Ribbon
4. In the Enable Audit option Select the Check Box Audit Log Enabled
5. configure the audit settings at the site collection level and below are the steps:
   1.Go to Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site Collection Audit Settings 
   2.Go to Site Collection Administration -> Audit Log Reports

Also, please checkout :[Audit log reports in SharePoint 2013](http://sureshpydi.blogspot.in/2013/05/audit-log-reports-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Find permission changes in SharePoint 2013](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/125875-how-to-find-permission-changes-in-sharepoint-2013-site-collection)

If need to generate the Audit Log Reports using PowerShell Command, I would suggest you can refer the helpful article:

[Create Auditing Reports in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://shokochino-sharepointexperience.blogspot.in/2013/05/create-auditing-reports-in-sharepoint.html)